# Algorithm for getting time difference in Python

Tags: python, time

I want to ask you about getting the time difference in Python. Suppose my starting time is 11:30am and ending at 1:00pm. The difference would be 1:00pm-11:30am = 90 minutes. I am new to python. Are there existing algorithms to solve these kinds of problems? I need then for my scheduling algorithm problem.

Your response would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2014, 1, 22, 11, 30)
end = datetime(2014, 1, 22, 13, 00)

minutes = (end - start).total_seconds() / 60.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but what's the proper format for datetime? :D

Comment: if you want to parse a datetime string take a look at `datetime.strptime` class method: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `datetime` for some reason here is another solution.

```
def minutes(time):
    time, ampm = time[:-2], time[-2:]
    t = time.split(":")
    time = int(t[0]) * 60 + int(t[1])
    if ampm == "pm":
        time += 12 * 60
    return time

def timeDiff(string):
  start, end = string.split("-")

  diff = minutes(end) - minutes(start)

  if diff < 0:
      diff += 24 * 60
  return diff

timeDiff('11:30am-1:00pm')
```

Comment: With respect: if OP cannot use a stdlib module, they need to learn how to use that module not hack their way around it. That's kind of what Python is :). That said, good outside the box, even if the box is well-formed and contains the perfect solution :)

Comment: I totally agree with you @adsmith. I had this code laying around and thought I might as well share it.